# Stored Procedure Out param through Java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I've below stored proc:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "demo"."run_demo"(v_sql IN VARCHAR2, return_code OUT number)
AS

i number;

BEGIN
return_code := 0;
execute immediate v_sql;
i := sql%rowcount;

    IF (i<1)
    THEN return_code := 1;
END IF;

EXCEPTION  
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    return_code := SQLCODE;
END;
```

I'm trying to call it from Java as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");      
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.10:1521:demo", "demo_app", "demo");

        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call demo.run_demo(?)}");
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
        cs.setString(1, "update demo.users set locale=''english'' where user_id = 2");

        cs.execute();

        System.out.println("out="+cs.getInt(1));
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But its returning error

> "Parameter Type Conflict".

Can any one tell me what's wrong?

Also, how can I return additional return_string in stored proc which would contain oracle error message (may be short description of error message)?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are missing a parameter. If you had have searched SO, you have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585550/parameter-type-conflict-when-calling-java-stored-procedure-within-another-java

Comment: I tried adding ? = call demo.run_demo(?) but that didn't help either. Can any one help me please?

Comment: Try cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.DECIMAL); instead of cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question @Alex van den Hoogen referred to is very similar, but is using a function rather than a procedure, which seems to have confused you slightly. The gist is the same; you aren't passing enough parameters in the Java call - you're setting and getting the same positional parameter, number 1. You need to do something like:

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call demo.run_demo(?,?)}");
cs.setString(1, "update demo.users set locale=''english'' where user_id = 2");
cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);

cs.execute();

System.out.println("out="+cs.getInt(2));
```

So in the `prepareCall`, `?,?` instead of just `?`; and `2` instead of `1` in `registerOutParameter` and `getInt`.

Or with the updated procedure from your [later question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598601/return-message-of-error-code-in-oracle-stored-proc), getting the error message too:

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call demo.run_demo(?,?,?)}");
cs.setString(1, "update demo.users set locale=''english'' where user_id = 2");
cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);

cs.execute();

System.out.println("out="+cs.getInt(2) + ":" + cs.getString(3));
```

Comment: How can we register out parameter of type array?
I am trying this - 
`

    cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, "CUSTOM_TYPE"); //The type is defined in procedure
    Array arr = cs.getArray(2);
    Resultset rs = arr.getResultSet();

`
And when i am trying to parse resultSet.  I am getting exception that ResultSetMetaData is unsupported feature. My CUSTOM_TYPE is a complex Java object, which internally has other child java objects. Or, for custom type, type should be object? if required I can post a new question for the same.